# pyOpenSSL + HTTPServer: Request doesn't complete until all processes finish

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I'd like to be able to respond to a GET by immediately returning a message and then starting a process to run in the background and finish a task. This works fine with BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer and extending BaseHTTPRequestHandler. However, when I follow the instructions [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/) to add SSL to the server, the response isn't sent until the subprocess finishes. Assuming that Firefox is displaying what it receives as it receives it, and double-checking with Firebug, it looks like nothing at all is sent until the subprocess completes. I tested in Chrome and saw the same result. Code below; I'm at a loss for how to continue debugging.

```
class SecureHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
  def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
    BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
    ctx.use_privatekey_file(SSL_CERT)
    ctx.use_certificate_file(SSL_CERT)
    self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type))
    self.server_bind()
    self.server_activate()
  def shutdown_request(self, request):
    request.shutdown()

class RecordingHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def setup(self):
    self.connection = self.request
    self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
    self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)
  def do_GET(self):
    key = 'abc'
    p = Process(target = some_func, args = (key,))
    # Some_func takes ~15 seconds to complete, and it logs its progress so that it's clear that the response is only sent after some_func is complete.
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    self.send_response(200)
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write('recording key ' + key)

def run():
  try:
    server = SecureHTTPServer(('', 8080), RecordingHandler)
    print 'Waiting for input on port 8080.'
    server.serve_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Received keyboard interrupt, exiting.'
    server.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to give up, restart, and try googling things again. I found [this solution](http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/):

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='path/to/localhost.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I still have no idea what was wrong with the previous setup, but this works just fine.